# Update XCode from command-line

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Is it possible to update `XCode` to a newer version without using the `XCode` GUI?  So far I can only find the [solution](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/6217746) for the `Xcode-CLI-tools`, but not the actual `XCode` itself.

Run this:

```
curl -Ls https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/index-3905972D-B609-49CE-8D06-51ADC78E07BC.dvtdownloadableindex | plutil -convert json -o - - | python -mjson.tool | less
```

Replace the URL in this simple shell script and run it:

```
#!/bin/sh
OSX_VERS=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F "." '{print $2}')

# Get Xcode CLI tools
# https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/index-3905972D-B609-49CE-8D06-51ADC78E07BC.dvtdownloadableindex
TOOLS=clitools.dmg
if [ ! -f "$TOOLS" ]; then
  if [ "$OSX_VERS" -eq 7 ]; then
      DMGURL=http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/command_line_tools_for_xcode_os_x_lion_april_2013.dmg
  elif [ "$OSX_VERS" -eq 8 ]; then
      DMGURL=http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/command_line_tools_for_xcode_os_x_mountain_lion_april_2013.dmg
  elif [ "$OSX_VERS" -eq 9 ]; then
      DMGURL=http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__late_october_2013/command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__late_october_2013.dmg
  fi
  curl "$DMGURL" -o "$TOOLS"
fi
TMPMOUNT=`/usr/bin/mktemp -d /tmp/clitools.XXXX`
hdiutil attach "$TOOLS" -mountpoint "$TMPMOUNT"
installer -pkg "$(find $TMPMOUNT -name '*.mpkg')" -target /
hdiutil detach "$TMPMOUNT"
rm -rf "$TMPMOUNT"
rm "$TOOLS"
exit
```

You may be interested to ask why would anyone want to do that, but I have an use case where we have 10+ Mac Minis to manage in our build farm and we would prefer not to update one-by-one on the GUI.

Comment: Are you running Xcode installs from the Mac App Store?

Comment: Let just said I don't, but I could.  My main is to install everything from scratch, even without having the the xcode-cli tools installed.

Comment: Could you update a single machine manually and then clone the tools over to the other machines on the local network?

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind on how to "clone the tools over to other machines".  Because if I can do that, I can just invoke other machines to download from apple directly.


I was thinking more related to using puppet or chef :-)